# Should graphics card be physically installed in PV when intalling conda tensorflow-gpu in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I'm following this guide and one thought that does occur is, is it OK to have the graphics card installed in the PC when I install tensorflow-gpu using anaconda?

Or analogous to a graphics card drivers should the card be left out while the install is being done?

https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/Install-TensorFlow-with-GPU-Support-the-Easy-Way-on-Ubuntu-18-04-without-installing-CUDA-1170/